# How do I deploy Complex Machine Learning Predictors?

Tags: deployment, machine-learning, kernel

So after I have spent a few days cleaning my data, preproceasing, and experimenting with a few different models (e.g. in R Studio) how do I realistically deploy the solution. 
Its straightforward if the model is a simple Model e.g Decision Tree, Logistic regression, as the model is obvious and the R Predictor model deployed into an commercial R Server with http endpoints etc.

My question is, what about complex pre processing ( e.g. PCA transforms, RBF kernels, or Random forests of 100 trees.) just as in the Validation phase, I would presume I would have to deploy R Scripts to preprocess, and PCA or apply RBF pre processing scripts etc to my deployment server ?

Does this mean for RBF I have to host all the original Training  data set alongside my SVM predictor ? RBF transform being a function of Training set or at least the support vectors.

And for Random Forest, I assume I have to upload all 500 or so Trees, as part of a very big model.

Answer (score 0):

First, export your R solution (data pre-processing steps and the model) into [PMML data format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language) using either the combo of [pmml](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmml/index.html) and [pmmlTransformations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmmlTransformations/index.html) packages, or the [r2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml) package. Second, deploy the PMML solution using [Openscoring](https://github.com/openscoring/openscoring) REST web service, [JPMML-Spark](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-spark), or whatever else PMML integration that fits your deployment needs.

PMML has no problem representing PCA, SVM with RBF kernel, tree ensembles, etc.

Comment: Thanks, useful.  I can see that PMML can represent models and pre-processing functions. And that would scale to supporting 100s or Trees from Random Forest.   I guess I am a bit naïve on RBF (Need to study more), but I thought the RBK kernel transformation was and remains a function of the Training set data. So to deploy RBF kernel  transformation implies distributing my Training set into my Predictor deployment.

Comment: Training a SVM with RBF kernel: `rbfSvm = e1071::svm(.., kernel = "radial", ..)`; then exporting to PMML: `pmml(rbfSvm)`. Or, could you show some of your R code and we could analyze what is the easiest way of PMML-izing it.

Answer (score 0):

A pure R vanilla solution for this problem. Most of the ensemble method provide utility to dump/save the learnt model. Learning is very time consuming and iterative process that should be done once. Post learning save/dump your R object. In the deployment have only scoring code. Scoring code will do all the data transformations and later on scoring.

For normal preprocessing you can reuse R code which was used in training. For complex processing like PCA again save the final model and just score/run data over saved PCA R object. Lastly post preprocessing score/run your data on learnt model and get final results.